# Can we use "as per your asking" when replying to queries?

Tags: phrases

I am very confused at this usage, very common among my friends. As far as I understand, the correct usage is *as per your query* or *as per your request*. My friends though use *as per your asking*. Which phrase is better?

Comment: I hear this constantly in the USA. It's completely commonplace in various regions.  Where are you from, user1?  As you suggest, it is a "pointless and weird" phrase.  But it's extremely common.  That language has unusual local constructs (such as "y'all") is totally unsurprising.

Comment: Its use may have originally been tongue in cheek, making fun of bureaucratic types.  If one of your friends is the thoughtful type, ask him or her to tell you what sort of connotations that phrase has.

Comment: Using a phrase as formal as "per your asking" in a conversation among friends seems like bringing a knife to a boxing match.  I'd suggest the alternatives "as you requested", or even "as requested".  Or, in even less formal settings, "like you asked".

Comment: "As per your asking" sounds very stilted for me. Perhaps there are regions where this expression is usual. But when communicating with people outside this region I would use a simpler and more normal formula.

Comment: I've never heard or read *as per your asking*.

Comment: "In response to your request ..."

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like something a non-native speaker would cobble together.  It does not sound very good, and not for just one reason alone.

For one thing, *as per* is redundant for just a simple *per*.

But that isn’t the worst thing, which is *asking* doesn’t work well as a count noun here. Neither does *ask*. That’s because we already have a word for that which is much more commonly used.  The whole thing should probably just be:

> per your request

That’s still a bit funny-sounding because *per* is super-formal, but it sounds less bad than the original.

Comment: "No, you can’t say that." unless you are in America, where it is absolutely established and normal (since about the 60s?) that one commonly adds really astoundingly convoluted/unnecessary constructs to statements.  My favorite example is always heard at airports: **"This will serve as the final boarding call for flight 17."**.  The first five words are in that totally bizarre category of American-absolutely-unnecessaryness.

Comment: Actually I think "asking" is a beautiful, "ye-olde-sounding", noun.  I wonder if it is so-used?  I better ask.

Comment: It does sound a bit foreign, but I think is grammatically legal: 'your asking' is a gerund. Stylistically, 'per your request' is better, but even 'per' sounds a little stilted.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, *per* is stilted. Can you think of a nicer way to say it?

Comment: @tchrist "From your request"? "Since you asked"? Recognition is easier than recall (it's easier to complain than create).

Comment: FWIW, this sort of phrasing is very common in the legal context and is used to establish causal relationships for legal purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using ***as you requested*** instead.

> *[As you requested](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22as+you+requested+here%22&biw=574&bih=377&prmd=vmin&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR-I7k4_7LAhVGCSwKHUHVDI8Q_AUICygG), here [is/are]...*