# Does "asking" as a noun have much, say, historic use?

Tags: etymology, american-english

There's a commonplace form in AmE, "as per your asking"...  (Note this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265960/can-we-use-as-per-your-asking-when-replying-to-queries) by a rightly confused non-native speaker.)

It occurred to me that "asking" makes a beautiful noun.

(Particularly if you pulp YA for a living ... consider say crap like "The Giver" .. that would be a perfect sequel title ... *"The Asking"*.  Sounds great, right?  I mean, it *cries* italics. You don't even have to add italics: you just look at it, and your deepest linguistic processes lean it to the right. It's sort of a linguistic optical typographical illusion.)

{Come to think of it, it's essentially the perfect title for *any* YA series book.  Vampire Academy: The Asking. Surviving the fog: The Asking. Etc.}

So ... it's time for the asking. (Political context.) Tonight comes the asking. (Marriage upcoming.) We're going to have the asking later.  (Child raising.)

My question, it has a ye-olde feel.  In fact, was "asking" used, perhaps .. in the 1800s? Or earlier?  Or has it never been used before?  Is it a recent coinage like other Americanisms, or?

---

*Doh: FYI I forgot about the common form "...for the asking", which seems related to, but not the same as, the above.*

Comment: I know *the asking* (sometimes pluralized) is archaic/dialectal for *reading of the marriage banns*, and I assume your first example simply equates *the asking* with *the election* (not that I've ever encountered that usage). But what does your third example have to do with ***child raising**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think in this example the parent is trying to quiet the incessant asking of questions by the child.

Comment: @aparente001: I'm sure Joe knows what he meant. But if I hadn't happened to know ***asking(s) = banns*** I'd have assumed that one was just a reference to ***popping the question*** (marriage proposal). I don't know any corresponding usage relating to the rearing of children, so I'm interested to know what Joe has in mind there.

Comment: Hi Fumble ... stern Dad speaking: **"So, a window has been broken. At this moment we do not know who did it. After supper and Bible, we will have the asking."**  Seems pretty straightforward "asking" == event where some question is asked.  (What else could it mean?)  Precisely as in the other three examples.

Comment: aparente - sure, I guess you could also use it that way.  "Stop asking that question incessantly son ... after dinner and Bible, we will have The Asking regarding that issue."

Comment: Hi Fumble -- that's interesting that "the asking" is, you mention, sometimes used for reading banns (presumably any sort of banns.  But that's simply exactly as per the usage I am asking about, so, it's an example of what I'm saying:  what historical period are you referring to? thanks...

Comment: Hi TChrist, IMO you should delete your comment-joke (the first comment here) as you make the same joke in the post.  Hence, it only adds clutter - and indeed one could argue diminishes the overall comic effect.

Comment: Fumble .. further, you mention "asking(s) = banns".  that seems completely incorrect.  It would be rather as if you said "games" means "death battle" (because of the common 'Hunger Games' usage).

Comment: @JoeBlow ***“banns*** Etymology: The same word as *ban* sb.1 ‘proclamation,’ in a specific use, in which it was from some cause regularly pronounced with long ā from 15th to 17th c. [...] The singular occurs in 15th c.; the plural only is found after.
1. Proclamation or public notice given in church of an intended marriage, in order that those who know of any impediment thereto may have opportunity of lodging objections. Phrases: ***to bid (obs.), ask, publish, put up the banns.”***

Comment: ["Free for the asking"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=free+for+the+asking&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfree%20for%20the%20asking%3B%2Cc0) has been popular since the late 1800s.

Comment: My first thought was I must have picked it up from Thomas Hardy's Wessex novels, but checking Google Books I find this in Dickens' *Dombey & Son:* [(They) will be joined together in the house of bondage, as soon as the askings is over](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as+soon+as+the+askings+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Victorian, anyway. In passing, I also know ***the askings*** (only ever plural) as a "dialectal, slang" equivalent to ***the asking price*** (a literal cash amount, or whatever else someone wants in return for the thing you're negotiating to obtain).

Comment: Hi TChrist .. uh, thanks! "banns" is used normally in everyday speech, today, in, say, Australia (in relation to weddings) and obviously in Germany, and I would imagine every BrE speaker knows it as a foreign word.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## *Þære spræce and þære ácsunge*

You suggested perhaps the 1800s for the origin of this use:  I’ll see that bet and raise you a millennium. Not an Americanism but perhaps a Wessexism, for some one thousand one hundred and thirty years ago in ᴀᴅ 885, King Ælfred the Great wrote not only:

> Hit is þeaw þære spræce and þære ácsunge.

but also:

> Mid ascunga.

Much more recently, Shakespeare wrote in *King Henry VIII*:

> Bestowing on him, at his asking, The Archbishopricke of Toledo.

And again in *Coriolanus*:

> Yet dare I neuer Deny your asking.

When Tennyson wrote *Tithonus*, he deliberately used this archaizing word to lend an air of antiquity to his verse:

> Then didst thou grant mine asking with a smile.

This deliberately hearkens back to olden times, where such things as this from the 1410 Pynson translation of *Bonaventura’s Myrrour* were readily found:

> Our lady··answereth sadly and shortly to theyr askynges.

Almost all such uses of *asking* save for Ælfred’s are now considered archaic or obsolete by the OED.  The King’s sense of the word was “the action of putting a question, interrogation, inquiry”, and this is the one still employed in *yours for the asking*.

Inquiries quickly become requests, and Shakespeare’s *Henry VIII* use (“the action of requesting a favour, gift, etc.; praying, begging”) is also still considered current. However, his *Coriolanus* use (“a petition, prayer, a supplication”) is now archaic.

There is also the regional use of *an asking* meaning the publication of marriage “banns” (proclamations of marriage), but this is very limited in distribution.

## Summary

Even though *askings* as a count noun has existed since time immemorial, it is now sufficiently obsolete that most spellchecking programs will flag it as an error in Modern English.

To most people, “What’s your ask?” and “Did he send in his asking yet?” sound like nothing but annoying business jargon instead of like forgotten pieces of English dug up from some ancient graveyard.

---

<sub>All citations are from the OED.</sub>

Comment: Actually, the relevant OED definition isn't #1 as given above. It's #3 *The action of requesting a favour, gift, etc.; **praying, begging*** (which even includes a citation from Sir Walter Scott of *a lass that may be had **for the asking***. I know it's a small distinction, but definition #1 is more general, since it includes simply asking *questions*, as opposed to specifically "pleading" for a "boon".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I added the others.

Comment: Okay, well I'll leave the comment, since others might find that fine distinction useful.

Comment: Amazing information, T !

Comment: Hi T .. myself (and probably many others), we here are not intelligent enough to read middle English (is that what it is?) .. perhaps you should offer a transliteration or respelling as well??

Comment: This is a great answer BTW.  The internet must be broken today.

Comment: **important** regarding your final aside.  are you saying that **you know that 'asking' is sometimes used in superfluous-busines-English** .. or did you just make that up on the spot (along the lines of: "heh, 'asking' would be perfect as a piece of superfluous business English"....)  What's the deal there?  cheers

Comment: @JoeBlow King Ælfred wrote in Old English. The word *thew* once meant habit or custom, so his first line runs something like “It is the custom of their speech and of their asking.”  The second quote of his is simply “Mid asking”.  Ask yes, an *ask* or an *asking* is current business jargon.

Comment: Interesting you call it a Wessex-ism: I would call it Germanic: Turning a verb indicating an activity into a noun designating a specific event consisting of that activity. Eg. To run-> The Run, just to name one. It is a common construct in most Germanic-origin languages. This specific one (ask) also appears in Dutch and German. E,g Dutch: "Het grote vragen is begonnen." The big asking has begun. Seen in a newspaper a few weeks ago when an inquiry was started into a police brutality case,

Comment: @Tonny Ælfred, King of Wessex.

Comment: @Tonny You call it Germanic—I’d call it at the very least Indo-European, and probably Indo-Uralic and whatever comes before that.

Comment: Is the use of "asking" in marriage banns really "regional?" I remember from my days in an Anglican church choir that the standard form of words, when they were read out at three successive weekly services, ended with "This is the first/second/third time of asking". It doesn't seem implausible that "an asking" was (and/or still is) used as a technical or legal term in the Church of England.

Comment: Is the ordering "cs" in "ácsunge" deliberate or accidental? It seems like it should be the other way around as "áscunge".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Glad you axed. :) Yes, the *cs* ordering is deliberate: it’s what was there. And yes, the King spelled it two different ways in two different things he wrote (as far as I can tell). There seems to be something about that word that makes it prone to metathesis not just now but in all ages, as there were also spellings with *x* going around in Middle English.  C. 1230 *Ancr. R.* 338 ― Of þe **axunge** mei uallen vuel. C. 1380 Wyclif *Wicket* 15 ― The puttynge awaye of fylthenes of the fleshe, and the **axynge** of good conscience. [Cf. 1 Pet. iii. 21 (revised) interrogation.]